# bootstrap customize navbar - logo on navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I was wondering if there is a way of achieving a navbar like the one on [this template](http://www.dynamic-template.com/template/cake-shop-html-template-300111804) using bootstrap.
I'd like to add a logo to the bootstrap navbar, but (like in the example) have it so that the logo extends further than the navbar's height and overlays directly over the image slider / carousel (without the white bar the example has). Also, have it centered in the navbar would be neat.

If this is not possible in Bootstrap, is there another way of doing this? I've tried doing it from scratch, but can't get it to work AND be responsive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/p58z2xgw/

A nav bar with left, center and right aligned items and a logo that overlaps the content.

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;

    background-image: url(http://jinglecheetah.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Demo-Logo.jpg);
    background-size: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li classsdropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="well">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just override the `navbar-brand` class so that it's centered and floats over the navbar..

```
.navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding:0;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/dv4rPK0Xws

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
You have to first make your icon have class .pull-right
and than create a navbar with all the div's in it having a picture background.
If you don't understand,
Go to the bootstrap homepage. It has tons of templates.